# Can I move JS code out of Svelte component file to other file js file?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am currently exploring Bucklescript/ReasonML with Svelte 3 for my next project. Typical Svelte component is a `.svelte` file:

```
<script>
  let name = 'world';
</script>

<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

**Instead, can I have `script` tag with `src` or equivalent to keep JS code in a separate file?**

```
<script src='./some-file.js'></script>
```

By moving the `js` code to a separate file, the target of the Bucklescript compiler (which is a JS file) could be used for the component.

Vue.js already supports this with their SFC `.vue` file.

> On a side note: I could use Vue.js for this but the presence Virtual DOM is problematic for legacy codebase. And, **Svelte** is diminishing at runtime and thus very much desirable. Also, the use `this` in Vue makes things awkward in Ocaml/Reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is possible with the [svelte.preprocess](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_preprocess) API, which you'd most commonly reach via the `preprocess` option in rollup-plugin-svelte or svelte-loader. Something like this should work (though I haven't tested it):

```js
const path = require( 'path' )
const fs = require( 'fs' )
...

plugins: [
  svelte({
    // ...
    preprocess: {
      script: ({ content, attributes, filename }) => {
        if ( 'string' === typeof attributes.src ) {
          const file = path.resolve(path.dirname(filename), attributes.src);
          const code = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8');
          return {code, dependencies: [file]};
        }
      }
    }
  })
]
```

Comment: At this point, it seems the code is only preprocessed once per `npm run dev`.  I've created some edits that I think fix and improve (adding a watch dependency) this sample.  Thanks @Rich-Harris!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this isn't possible right now.

What you could do is export everything you need from the js file, and then import them in the component: https://svelte.dev/repl/1d630ff27a0c48d38e4762cf6b0c2da5?version=3.7.1

```html
<script>
 import { name } from './mycode.js'
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
```

```
export let name = 'World';
```

However that would only be a partial solution as any mutation of data occurring within the file would not trigger a re-render of the DOM, as Svelte would not compile the .js file and would not be able to add its own code invalidating the values: https://svelte.dev/repl/c4b41b769ed747acb01a02a9af33e545?version=3.7.1

```html
<script>
 import { name, handleClick } from './mycode.js'
</script>

<h1 on:click={handleClick}>Hello {name}!</h1>
```

```
export let name = 'World';
export const handleClick = () => {
    name = 'Everyone';
}
```

But that doesn't mean you can't be tricky if you are willing to go the extra mile to achieve this: https://svelte.dev/repl/8e259df629614ac99cb14cfae2f30658?version=3.7.1

```html
<script>
 import { name, handleClick } from './mycode.js'

 const onClick = () => {
     handleClick();
     name = name;
 }
</script>

<h1 on:click={onClick}>Hello {name}!</h1>
```

```
export let name = 'World';
export const handleClick = () => {
    name = 'Everyone';
}
```

The extra line `name = name` forcing the DOM update.

Comment: That will work but it is too much boilerplate. It goes against the principles of Svelte. Looks like I will have to rest it.